# Undefined symbol error in Centos compile

Tags: dynamic, dll, compilation, shared-libraries

I have run into an interesting problem. I am compiling my application code and was using **ace library(*version 6_1_1*)** on my centos 6 machine. Everything worked fine. When i look at the symbols of the ace library compiled on centos 6 machine, it looks like this:

> bash-4.1$ nm ace/libACE.so.6.1.1 | grep handle_sig 000f9430 T
>   _ZN15ACE_Sig_Adapter13handle_signalEiP7siginfoP8ucontext 000b84d0 T _ZN17ACE_Event_Handler13handle_signalEiP7siginfoP8ucontext 00079f10 T _ZN18ACE_Service_Config13handle_signalEiP7siginfoP8ucontext 000f26d0 T _ZN19ACE_Process_Manager13handle_signalEiP7siginfoP8ucontext 0007ee70 T _ZN19ACE_Service_Manager13handle_signalEiP7siginfoP8ucontext
>   000cf920 T
>   _ZN20ACE_MMAP_Memory_Pool13handle_signalEiP7siginfoP8ucontext 000f8b80 T _ZN22ACE_Shared_Memory_Pool13handle_signalEiP7siginfoP8ucontext
>   bash-4.1$

But when i compile the same project on **centos 7 machine**, the symbols change:

> bash# nm ace/6_1_1/ace/libACE.so.6.1.1 | grep handle_sig 000fa090 T
>   _ZN15ACE_Sig_Adapter13handle_signalEiP9siginfo**_t**P8ucontext 000b9570 T
>   _ZN17ACE_Event_Handler13handle_signalEiP9siginfo**_t**P8ucontext 0007e070 T
>   _ZN18ACE_Service_Config13handle_signalEiP9siginfo**_t**P8ucontext 000f3500 T
>   _ZN19ACE_Process_Manager13handle_signalEiP9siginfo**_t**P8ucontext 00081cb0 T
>   _ZN19ACE_Service_Manager13handle_signalEiP9siginfo**_t**P8ucontext 000d1990 T
>   _ZN20ACE_MMAP_Memory_Pool13handle_signalEiP9siginfo**_t**P8ucontext 000f93d0 T
>   _ZN22ACE_Shared_Memory_Pool13handle_signalEiP9siginfo**_t**P8ucontext bash#

Notice that there is an extra **_t** in siginfo. So, my application which links this library fails to launch during run time giving me that error:

> symbol "_ZN17ACE_Event_Handler13handle_signalEiP9siginfo_tP8ucontext"
>   not found

Another interesting point to note is that if i copy the compiled ace library from my **centos 6 box** into **centos 7 box**, my application works fine.

I am lost on how to fix this issue. Any help in this regards will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

> But when i compile the same project on centos 7 machine, the symbols change:

Probably Glibc on Centos 7 has changed one of the types in public headers which caused mangler to emit different symbols:

```
$ echo _ZN15ACE_Sig_Adapter13handle_signalEiP7siginfoP8ucontext | c++filt
ACE_Sig_Adapter::handle_signal(int, siginfo*, ucontext*)
$ echo _ZN15ACE_Sig_Adapter13handle_signalEiP9siginfo_tP8ucontext | c++filt
ACE_Sig_Adapter::handle_signal(int, siginfo_t*, ucontext*)
```

Notice that new method now uses `siginfo_t` rather than siginfo (you'll see hundreds of complaints if you google for "siginfo_t vs siginfo").

> Another interesting point to note is that if i copy the compiled ace
>   library from my centos 6 box into centos 7 box, my application works fine.

That's backward compatibility - you can (usually) run apps linked on older version of distro on it's newer versions.

On the contrary, forward compatibility (in your case - linking old application against new library) is not guaranteed.

> I am lost on how to fix this issue.

If you are only interested in new CentOS - rebuild all your code. If you want to run on older versions - build on the oldest and distribute that.

Comment: Thanks for responding back. I have been both compiling the application and the library on the new CentOS itself i.e. Centos 7.2. The symbols are different when i compile it on Centos 6 vs Centos 7 as you pointed out above. I am also using the latest glibc to compile. Any pointers to debug this further?